# Communication between two STMs over 2 meter with small latency

Tags: stm32, spi, latency

I want to send messages back and forth between two STM32s. Probably STM32F407VET6, but it would be nice if I can try already something for a simple one (STM32F103C8T6).

My requirements:

- round trip delay time: preferably 1 ms max (excluding processing), for messages with a payload of around 8 bytes.
- distance around 2 meters
- speed: pure data: around 128 kbps (excluded overhead) so probably around 200 kbps

I checked between SPI and I2C, and seems that SPI is easier (to setup) and I have enough GPIO pins.

However, I read that 2 meters and fast data rate might be a problem. Also I cannot find info about the round trip delay.

Of course I can check all this myself, but it saves me a lot of effort to set this up.

For the cabling between the two STMs I am intending to use an RS232 connector (and probably cable), but if there are better alternatives, please let me know (UTP cable maybe and internet connector?). Or are there more appropriate cabling/connectors for this?

(update, link to MCP2551 according answer remark)
MCP2551 adapter: [adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-MCP2551-high-speed-CAN-protocol-controller-bus-interface-module/32473879548.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.38.ozWu76&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10068_10209_5430020_10304_10307_10301_10137_10060_10155_10154_5370011_10056_10055_10054_10059_100031_10099_5400020_5410011_10103_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051_5380020_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10177_10110_10111_10112_5390011_10113_10114_10312_10313_10314_10315_10078_10079_10210_10073_5420011-10050_10111,searchweb201603_16,ppcSwitch_4&btsid=1176338b-93ee-4d67-a280-f0fdb4ed66a7&algo_expid=cc42e7b7-69b2-4186-b4d2-ae2ffaa40c18-5&algo_pvid=cc42e7b7-69b2-4186-b4d2-ae2ffaa40c18)

Comment: Look at RS485, it's differential so will be more reliable over long distances

Comment: What type of STMs? Just to know what are the possibilities.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I updated the question.

Comment: @Colin__s I don't have experience with RS485 ... would I need additional hardware for that? (and what?)

Comment: You will need a transceiver for each end of the link, these will talk to the STMs via serial

Comment: @Colin__s I assume you mean for example a MAX3485CPA ?

Comment: +1 for Colin's suggestion. So much easier than SPI between two micros and I2C is slow. I'd also suggest you make it full duplex for ease of use as it's point-to-point.

Comment: @DiBosco I checked for a MAX3488CPA (full duplex) and MAX3485 (half duplex). I can find the first for 15 cents, the last for around 5 euro ... can I just add two MAX3488 and use 'full' duplex?

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You certainly can. Just ensure you have the Rx and Tx pins on the two transceivers set to the correct levels.

Comment: @DiBosco ... you mean 3.3/5V? The MAX3485 works on 3.3V (as the MAX385 on 5V). STM32s work on 3.3V... Probably I will not use Arduinos anyway (on 5V).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers I mean that you set the direction of the transceiver ~RE and DE pins to the correct levels for each one. So, for the transmit chip they should both be high and the receive both low.

Comment: @Colin__s you should certainly take the glory for this one ;)

Comment: This is unanswerable - if you want to send 100 bits of data at 100 kbps, the time taken will be 1 ms but you don't state how much data needs to be sent and neither do you state the turn-around time to process the message received and respond.

Comment: @Andy aka ...good point, I updated my question: added - round trip delay time: preferably 1 ms max (excluding processing), for messages with a payload of around 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with SPI you have to face is clocking speed and distance - if the clocking speed is too high then the data coming back from the slave might be too much misaligned to be able to adequately receive it. That's the short story.

So, if you transmit at 128 kbps then the clock is 128 kHz and one symbol of data is approximately 7.8 us. You then have to consider how long it takes for a data to fly down the cable and that is based approximately on 70% of the speed of light.

Light travels 1 metre in 3.33 ns and so 2 metres of cable takes about 10 ns to be received and, when the slave responds, it does so on clock edges that are 10 ns "late" compared to the master's perception of time so, there's another 10 ns to add on to the overal skew of data coming back to the master.

So, 20 ns of skew in a basic clock period of 7.8 us isn't really going to be a problem.

Comment: And I can use 128 kbps for SPI with 2 meter 'cable' ? Because I already imagined the 'transmission' speed would not be a problem (which you calculated including some parts I didn't know off, like 70% and the clock edges).

Comment: After I tried to use SPI on two STM32's (never tried, only on Arduino), I'm going to think about what cable/connector would be best.

Comment: You can send SPI many, many metres in one direction (from master to slave) with appropriate cable drivers and line terminators - the problem arises on the return journey of the slave response - providing the overall "there and back" delay is a fraction of the clock period you'll be OK.

Comment: For instance, with a clocking period of 7.8 us, if the "there and back" delay approached half of 7.8 us, the SPI master will be trying to clock data from the SPI slave on the wrong edge and you would get sh1t data. I would say that you could adequately receive slave transmissions from a cable that introduced a delay of one-eighth of 7.8 us. That's about 1 us or 200 metres. However, with a cable this long you will need proper drivers and teminators to avoid reflections and you would certainly consider RS485 for this and asynchronous transmissions.

Comment: I probably don't need more than 2 meters, but it's good to know I can go for more. I think I have to read about cable drivers/line terminators.

Comment: It might be worth adding a checksum or similar in your protocol layer.  With SPI you clock in something on the clock edge, but it's not very noise resilient.

Comment: @Colin__s That shouldn't be any problem (to add 1 or 2 bytes per message).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try CANBus. STM32F4 chips have internal CANBus interface and you can easly find software libraries from KEIL. You should use CAN transceiver IC's like MCP2551 and setup your network. CANBus is a good selection for node to node communication. I2C and SPI are **mostly** used for MCU to sensor communication in same board. CANBus is a differential communication, it is very durable due to electrical noise which might be a problem at 2m distance. Also it can provide your 
communication speed requirements.

Comment: Thanks ... never tried CANbus before (I don't have an F4 yet, but I see even the simplest F1 has one I can test). Can I ask what kind of cables/connectors are used normally for CANbus?

Comment: First of all, in CANBus network you dont need any coaxial cable. You just need 2 cables (CAN High & CAN Low) and the cables must be twisted paired. In "twisted pair" system, you just twist 3-5 twists per inch that 2 cables together. Also nodes must have common ground in CANBus. You can easly use rs232 connectors in that system. Which is easy to implement on board and soldering.

Comment: Going to check for twisted pair cables (guess I need 3 cables at least, one for CAN high, one for CAN low and for GND?)

Comment: There is no need to twist GND cable, but it is ok. I almost forgot that simple information, you should use 120 ohm resistors between CANH and CANL at the both ends of network.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with no need for twisting GND cable ... I would assume I should find a 3 wire twisted cable (wire for Can high, Can low and gnd) which both ends I solder to a DB9 connector?

Comment: I updated my answer to the link to the MCP2551 you proposed. It has some additional components, if it does not have the 120 ohm resistors, I will add them myself (on the breadboard)

Comment: I mean, you should twist only CANL and CANH cable (you dont need to find any specific cable, you can twist the cables yourself) but you can twist GND cable with CANH and CANL there is no problem. About MCP2551 and resistors, you should add 120 ohm R's by yourself. You should solder CANH and CANL on separate pins of DB9 after that you should solder 120 ohm resistors between that pins at both side (node1 and node2).

Comment: Maybe my interpretation of cable and wire is incorrect. Would I need two DB9 connectors (one per cable)? I thought I could use 3 pins of the DB9 (CANH, CANL, GND). And those 3 wires are inside one 'cable' (sorry for my maybe stupid question, I'm a newbie regarding 'cables' in this matter).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63790/discussion-between-batu92k-and-michel-keijzers).

Comment: (in case you couldn't read the chat) ... thank you very much for your detailed answers and explanations and for the nice chat!